# What is the relationship between genus and crossing numbers

Tags: graph-theory

I have some questions about topology graph theory and algorithms.

Suppose given a graph with genus $k$ ($k\ge1$), if we want to draw this graph on the plane, there are at least $k$ crossing numbers of edges. In other words, there is a drawing for a graph with genus $k$ on the plane with exactly $k$ crossing numbers. Is this correct?

I ask this question because I have an algorithm which is only valid for planar graph. I want to generalize it to some constant genus $k$ scenarios. My first step is considering genus is equal to 1. If the above question is correct, then a genus 1 graph has a drawing on the plane with only 1 pair of edges crossing. By decomposing the graph and separating the crossing edges into two different part,  I can get two planar graphs.

PS: for general version of this problem has been proved to be $NPC$. Given a nonplanar graph $G=(V,E)$ and a integer $k$, to check whether there is a vertex set or edge set deletion from $G$ produces a planar graph $G'$ and cardinality smaller than $k$.

PPS: One more question appended. Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with genus $k$, is there any efficient algorithm to find a edge $e$ such that $G[E\setminus e]$ has genus $k-1$. I called this kind of edge as critical edge.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore this question, I am wrong!

You would need to remove at least 3 edges from K_6 to obtain a planar graph.